# if/else statement in Java

Tags: java

```
class if1
{

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int a = 100;
    if(a==100); //Expected a compile error but did not get one.    
  }    
}
```

I expected the compiler to issue me an error but surprisingly it compiled just fine.
What is the rationale for a compiler to ignore whether the "if" statement has any statements to process or not.
Why does it not throw an error like in the below case ?

```
class if2
{

  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    int a = 100;
    if(a == 101) //Compiler complains here...
    else
    {
      System.out.println("in else");

    }
  }
}
```

In the above statement, the compile complains that "if" clause does not have anything to process.

Can someone tell me why ?

Comment: If condition needs atleast one statement. In the first case it is ';'. In the second case, it is blank.

Comment: @qasimzee `if` needs *exactly* one statement, or a block.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
if(a==100); //Expected a compile error but did not get one.
```

No compiler error as this is assumed to be an empty if block as it is terminated by semicolon `(;)`

```
if(a == 101) //Compiler complains here...
```

This is an incomplete if block, there should be at least one statement in if or else it should be terminated by `semicolon(;)` as above. As the if is not complete so else will also not make any sense to compiler.

Comment: If it helped, simply accept it :-) The practice of accepting an answer helps other facing the same problem.

Comment: Actually, there must be _exactly_ one statement for each branch (which may be a [block](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.2)).

Comment: Can I do this: if (a==0); else ;

Answer (score 2):

In the first there is one statement `;`

```
 if(a == 101)
 ; // Hence there is no compile time error.
```

But in the second thee is no statement. It is an empty block.

For the second statement you have to give it a block. Something like this:-

```
if(a == 101)
{
}
```

or

```
if(a == 101);
```

Answer (score 2):

Ok, take it this way, your first statement is equivalent to:

```
if (a == 10)
    ;   // Here you have one statement, but that's an empty statement.
```

So, you do have a statement, though an empty one. So, compiler is ok with it. Just putting a *semi-colon* is a way to write an empty block, without curly braces. So, the above `if` block is really equivalent to:

```
if (a == 10) { }
```

In 2<sup>nd</sup> case,

```
if (a == 10)
    // No statement here
```

The compiler expects a statement after the `if` block, which it doesn't find.

Answer (score 1):

There is issue with sytax. java supports specified syntax for `if-else` and `if`.

```
if(a==100); // Empty if block
if(a==100)  // if block following with single statement
  System.out.println("a: "+a);
```

Both are valid `if` statement.

For the case `if-else` -

```
if(a==100)
   System.out.println("a: "+a);
else
   System.out.println("else ");
or    
if(a==100){
   System.out.println("a: "+a);
}else{
   System.out.println("else ");
}
```

Both of this are valid. But

```
if(a == 101) 
else{...}
```

This one is not invalid, due to if statement does not have proper ending.

Answer (score 0):

An `if` statement without an `else` permits the "then" clause to be empty; an `if` statement with an `else` does not.

The reasons for this are explained in some detail in the Java Language Specification ([§14.5 Statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.5)):

> As in C and C++, the if statement of the Java programming language suffers from the so-called "dangling `else` problem," illustrated by this misleadingly formatted example:

```
if (door.isOpen())
   if (resident.isVisible())
      resident.greet("Hello!");
else door.bell.ring();  // A "dangling else"
```

> The problem is that both the outer `if` statement and the inner `if` statement might conceivably own the `else` clause. In this example, one might surmise that the programmer intended the `else` clause to belong to the outer `if` statement.
>
> The Java programming language, like C and C++ and many programming languages before them, arbitrarily decrees that an `else` clause belongs to the innermost `if` to which it might possibly belong. This rule is captured by the following grammar:
>
> ....
>
> Statements are thus grammatically divided into two categories: those that might end in an `if` statement that has no `else` clause (a "short if statement") and those that definitely do not.
>
> Only statements that definitely do not end in a short `if` statement may appear as an immediate substatement before the keyword `else` in an `if` statement that does have an else clause.
>
> This simple rule prevents the "dangling else" problem. The execution behavior of a statement with the "no short `if`" restriction is identical to the execution behavior of the same kind of statement without the "no short `if`" restriction; **the distinction is drawn purely to resolve the syntactic difficulty.**

Answer (score 0):

```
if(a==100); //Expected a compile error but did not get one.
```

This is perfectly valid(not of any use though). You are saying if a variable is equal to 100 do nothing.  Above is equivalent to

```
if(a==100){}
```

But

```
if(a == 101) //Compiler complains here...

else
{
 System.out.println("in else");

}
```

in above case you have a else hanging in middle of nowhere. If-else is a construct and must be together(if statement can be independent though). Logically speaking why would there be an else if there is no if.

Answer (score 0):

There is sytax error. java supports specified syntax for if-else and if.

```
     if(a==100);
```

After the statement there is no semicolon(;) so block as it is terminated by semicolon

```
if(a==100)
System.out.println("a: "+a);
else
 {
 System.out.println("in else");

 }
```

This code will be execute.

Answer (score 0):

`if(a == 101)` here you are getting error due to this is not an statement. you have to put (;). 
There is no issue code like  `if(a == 101);`

We can do some thing like this with `if` statements.

```
 if(a==2)
 System.out.println("This is correct");
```

so we can use this as follows too

```
 if(a==0)
  ;
```

But you can't do like follows, Since you have to put (;)

```
if(a==2)
System.out.println("This is correct")
```

Then following also not valid

```
if(a==2)
```

Answer (score 0):

c-heritage languages permit an empty statement which makes possible a `for` loop of the form:

```
for(/*initialization*/;/*iteration*/;/*condition*/){}
```

This allows the programmer to optionally run code at initialization (such as for local variables), iteration (increment/decrement a value, etc), and finally test for a condition on which the loop will break.

Because this is possible, empty statements are also possible.

```
;
;;
if(false);
for(;;);
```

etc. Are all legal.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Java Language Specification](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.6), an *empty statement* (a semicolon by itself) is a perfectly legal statement that can be used anywhere a statement is allowed. Your first case

```
if (a==100);
```

is exactly that. The second case:

```
if (a==100)
else { . . . }
```

is missing the statement that is required for the `if` branch. (See the [JLS specification of the `if` statement syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9).)

Answer (score 0):

The simicolon is the empty statement. Writing `;` is very similar to `{}`. It does nothing. The compiler expects a statement after the if condition. So having an else immediately after the if condition will give you a compiler error, but having a statement (including the empty statement) will not.

Answer (score 0):

`char charVar = ’z’;`

Write an `if` statement that if the variable holds a, the condition is true and then tell the user the value of your variable is a.